# Why does the time_field store a default date as well in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have written a code something like this in my form_for

```
= f.time_field :start_time, class: 'form-control'
```

and the data type used in the underlying table is `time`.
But when I store a time with this field, it also stores a default date `2000-01-01` and upon displaying the value of that column I get a value as `2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC`, whereas I just want to store and display the time. I don't want the date part of it.

I want to know how the "time" data type works in rails and how can i get it to store only the time and not the date, and display the same. The question  [Rails. How to store time of day (for schedule)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973225/rails-how-to-store-time-of-day-for-schedule) doesn't address the time data type whereas gives different ways to store and operate on time values.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look into [seconds_since_midnight()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-seconds_since_midnight)

```
def seconds_since_midnight
  sec + (min * 60) + (hour * 3600)
end
```

This is how you use it.

```
Time.now.seconds_since_midnight
```

This way I can do a simple query to find out if a venue is open:

```
Model.where("start_time > ? and end_at < ?", Time.now.seconds_since_midnight, Time.now.seconds_since_midnight)
```

I hope that this helps