# A way to store date and time in postgresql ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Which way of storing date and time will provide the quickest search for this data segments if I plan to search separately for each? I always store in datetime type, but maybe it would be more pragmatically to store in the separate columns(e.g. date and time database types) for this purpose?

Comment: Not directly a solution to your question, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15350965/6611487) seems just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run any benchmarks but I could only see the need to saving them as different columns if you're planning on doing massive - and I mean massive - queries on Date alone.

```
timestamp (with time zone) 8 bytes  both date and time, with time zone
date                       4 bytes  date (no time of day)
time (without time zone)   8 bytes  time of day (no date)
time (with time zone)      12 bytes times of day only, with time zone
```

So if you store them separately, it takes at least more +4bytes, or +8 if you keep the time zone on the `time` field.

If you're going to have a massive number of rows to query, where you'll be querying only for `Date` then it might make sense, otherwise I don't think so (in fact it might still make no sense since with a massive number of rows it will also use more unnecessary space possibly offsetting any perceived advantage).

I have used `integer` fields representing `Dates` (up 'till months - e.g. 201704 as index), but because the records were reflecting unique monthly records and it made sense, there's no Date format reflecting only Year+Month, otherwise PG is already quite optimised to handle date timestamp situations.

Comment: datetime and timestamp migration types in Rails are both mapped to PostgreSQL's TIMESTAMP with time zone datatype, right?

Comment: I don't think so, I think you need to take care of saving it correctly. This might help you figuring it out: http://rpanachi.com/2016/07/04/ruby-is-time-to-talk-about-timezones